# Adding categories to search refinement panel

Tags: search, refinement-panel

Is it possible to add new categories or links to search refinement panel that will be pulled from a custom 'Categories' SharePoint list?

**EDIT:** I am not using FAST Search but the question applies to FAST Search also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to define a SharePoint column (e.g. Categories) as a managed property. You can then modify the "Filter Category Definition" of your refinement panel.

It is outlined in that blog post in a little more detail:
http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2009/12/09/adding-search-refinements-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Just in case it does not work at first: Make sure that you unchecked the "Use default Configuration" checkbox and that your "MetadataThreshold Configuration" is suitable for you.

Comment: This is kind of a static way of adding refinements. What I am looking for is a more dynamic way. When I add a new item in one of my lists, I want the title of that new list item to appear on refinement panel.

Comment: The solution Alex suggests is a dynamic way. Once the crawler gets the new item (incremental will do), the category in the panel is updated.